# Share internet from a computer to a another computer via a normal USB

Tags: windows-10, usb, network-shares

I want to share the internet from my laptop to my desktop computer without a USB bridging cable. Just like USB tethering on Android. Is there any third-party software or a built-in option to do it?

OS: Windows 10

Comment: https://smallbusiness.chron.com/two-computers-using-usb-cable-56788.html : The second point explains why is it necessary to use a bridged USB cable (Sorry, wrong link earlier :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we can discuss the software you should check the hardware.  Host-to-host communications was not possible until USB 3.0 and later.  Having a computer with USB4 on one or both ends might make this easier.  USB 2.0 and earlier does not support host-to-host communications as part of the protocol.

For USB 2.0 networking between two computers would take a bridging cable or a pair of adapter cables.  At this point it may be easier to set up, lower cost, and give faster communications if using a pair of WiFi or Bluetooth adapters than any wire.  Maybe 100 Mbps Ethernet will do nicely, as fast and cheap as a bridging cable.

Many newer computers with USB-C ports may support host-to-host communications with a simple USB-C to USB-C cable assuming both computers have USB-C ports.  If both of these USB-C ports support Thunderbolt and/or USB4 then setup of a network should be trivial.  That's not technically USB though so I don't know if I should explain that in a question about USB.

If only one computer has USB-C, or one or both computers lack Thunderbolt/USB4, then perhaps this can still work if the computer or computers support Windows CE or whatever it is called today.  This puts that computer USB-C port into a device mode so it can appear as a network device to the other computer that takes on the host role.  This is not likely some driver or something one can install.  If the computer does not support this from the manufacturer, and is not documented in their operation manual, then this is not likely to work.

If one or both computers have USB-A ports then a special USB-A to USB-A cable may help.  These cables have the USB 3.0 "super speed" data lines and ground connected on both ends of the cable but the cables used for the USB 2.0 backward compatibility are unconnected.  These are often called "debug" cables as their primary use is to debug drivers and other low level software.  The operating system supports these cables but not for creating a network.  If someone figured out how to make these cables do more then I have yet to see it.

A big problem with host-to-host networking on USB is that the connections and protocol were not built for it.  There's no hardware in the USB-A port to detect a "debug" cable being plugged in.  Even some USB-C ports won't have the hardware to announce it is present to the other computer.  Then is the software, one computer has to take on a client mode to the other as a host.  Thunderbolt works this out, but again that's not USB even though it uses the USB-C connector.  A laptop that charges from USB-C will enter client mode when plugged into a desktop so that it can charge its batteries.  The software to use this connection for more than charging, such as creating a network connection is not likely available just yet.

USB 3.0 is the minimum to make this work.  One or both computers with USB-C will make it easier.  Thunderbolt/USB4 should make it trivial.  If both computers have USB-A then you will have to buy a special purpose cable anyway, it may as well be one with a bridging chip in the middle.